# Upgrading 32-bit XFS filesystem to 64-bit

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

What would be the procedure for upgrading XFS filesystems from 32-bit to 64-bit?  What damage or issues would arise from accessing XFS fs that was formatted on a 32-bit OS with a 64-bit OS?

To recap, I had some issues with NFS to a fileserver that was recently upgraded.  Part of the upgrade was to move to a 64-bit OS.  The problems with apps hanging on file access over NFS also occurred on the local machine.  At this point I noticed the partition was XFS.  Somewhere I recall that XFS is not portable between 32-bit and 64-bit systems.  Is this correct?

A run of xfs_check showed nothing wrong and xfs_repair ran successfully.

Update:

Found the following on the Ubuntu wiki:

"The journal is currently not 32-bit / 64-bit portable. Before mounting a xfs prevously used on 32-bit linux in 64-bit linux (or different arch) the journal has to be emptied using xfs_repair." -- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XFS

There is no date on this page.

Leaves me wondering why the system behaves strangely, though.

Comment: Makes a bit more sense now, with a particular implementation having a bug. Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're referring to XFS running on Linux... You shouldn't have any conversion issues going from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system on XFS. The filesystem won't need to be modified.

Comment: +1, The only difference are a few upper limits of things, going from 32 to 64 would simply increase the limits.